# How to flush DNS caches that parse domain name to IP address in Windows 7 and 10?

Tags: windows, dns, cache

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20flush%20DNS%20caches%20that%20parse%20domain%20name%20to%20ip%20address%20in%20Windows%207%20and%2010%3F&oq=How%20to%20flush%20DNS%20caches%20that%20parse%20domain%20name%20to%20ip%20address%20in%20Windows%207%20and%2010%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.615j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) came up with [this answer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/domain-name-system-faq#1TC=windows-7) that use `ipconfig /flushdns` command.

Though on my Windows 7 and Windows 10, this command doesn't help me to get the latest IP address for a given domain name - at the same time yesterday, I on Windows and my co-worker on Linux machine parse our domain name to see the IP address after we changed it on domain cpanel.

The IP on my PC stayed the same while Linux machine can read the new value.

So my question is, how can I flush/clear DNS cache in Windows and that works?

Comment: have you checked your hosts file?

Comment: No I didn't. Check what @Kilisi

Answer (score 1):

Use an elevated command prompt to flush DNS.

Check for hardcoded entries in the hosts file

Also, you might have different DNS Servers on your Linux and Windows boxes.

If you are in control of the DNS try to reload it too

Comment: Used an administrator prompt and tried `Clear-DnsClientCache`, `ipconfig /flushdns` and still `nslookup example.com` gave me an outdated result. I know it's outdated and Windows specific, because a lookup on a cloud server gives me a different answer, and the domain that cannot be accessed on my Windows browser works fine on my iPad on the same network. Interestingly, even after I changed the DNS server to `9.9.9.9` (which gives the correct A answer with `dig`), Windows is none the wiser. Would really like to know how to fix this.

Comment: "Check for hardcoded entries in the hosts file":

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Good point, but It's not that, I use it to add `.local` IP addresses. I posted [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1746796/how-to-refresh-windows-dns-a-and-ns-records) with more details, but it resolved itself after a while. Still, I'd like to improve my knowledge and understanding on it.