# How to refresh Windows DNS A and NS records

Tags: windows, dns

When I deleted the `NS` records for a domain I could see the changes pretty quickly with the `host` command on a Linux VM running on a Windows 11 host:

```bash
$ host -t ns example.com
example.com has no NS record
```

However, hours have passed since I added the new `NS` records and this is still the same result. Used an administrator PowerShell prompt and tried `Clear-DnsClientCache`, `ipconfig /flushdns`, and still `nslookup example.com` gave me an outdated result. I know this issue is machine specific, because a lookup on a cloud server gives me a different answer, and the domain that cannot be accessed on my Windows Edge browser works fine on my iPad on the same Wi-Fi network, and even on the same Windows laptop if I use a VPN.

Interestingly, even after I changed the DNS server on the Wi-Fi adapter to `9.9.9.9` (which gives the correct `A` record with `dig`), Windows is none the wiser.

This will probably resolve itself eventually, but I am curious to understand what is going on and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Has the serial number been increased? Have the SOA timers expired?

Comment: Interesting, have to remember to check that next time. They're all in sync now, as expected, so I can no longer reproduce this issue. But would there be a way to force a "refresh", or whatever the correct term or action is, on the system that doesn't have the correct records?

Comment: You would likely be dealing with multiple systems, each with their own view. You would have to go around each and clear their cache if applicable. It's something you mainly just have to live with or to set the timers to a very low timeout, think seconds or minutes rather than hours. You can get the timers with `host -t soa example.com`. `ipconfig /flushdns` should clear it on windows.

Comment: Yes, they definitely had their own "views" at some point yesterday, but `ipconfig /flushdns` with an admin console didn't change it in this case, hence the question... thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is the serial number did not increase and/or `rndc reload` was not issued on the linux box.

Comment: I had not done `rndc reload`, but that's to control the name server itself, not sure if that's what's wanted here. The Linux VM is one thing but I think the issue was on the Windows host because Edge refused to connect to the same domain that was fine on the iPad on the same network. So I want to understand what was happening and how to fix it if happens again. But it sorted itself out now, so it's hard to dig further.